# How can I insert array data to a file?

Tags: php, arrays

I have created two arrays and I want all the information from both to save to a .txt file. I want it to save in the format ('DATE' 'RAINFALL') inside the file. I tried many sources for help and I still can't get it to save. How can I do it? Thank you

The format inside the txt file

[image: This is the format inside the .txt file I want]

Code I currently have:

```
$rainf_array = array($rainf0, $rainf1, $rainf2, $rainf3, $rainf4, $rainf5, $rainf6 );

    $date_array = array($date0, $date1, $date2, $date3, $date4, $date5, $date6 );


   //Input value is saved to the file

   {
     $fileHandle = fopen($fileName, "w");

      fwrite($fileHandle, $date_array .'' . $rainf_array . ",\n" );


     fclose($fileHandle);
   }
```

Comment: You could use `implode` or iterate over the array and concatenate to a string... or use a CSV parser, something like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php, that would be a CSV though although maybe you can change delimiter to a space (I would use some delimiter).

Comment: Yeah but I want inside the file's format to look like this ('Date' 'Rainfall'). How do I make it look like that?

Comment: You should encapsulate the values in quotes, and use a delimiter. This is going to be hard to use in the future. I'd have `'yyyy-mm-dd', '##'` or `'yyyy-mm-dd', ##`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
$date_array = array($date0, $date1, $date2, $date3, $date4, $date5, $date6);
$rainf_array = array($rainf0, $rainf1, $rainf2, $rainf3, $rainf4, $rainf5, $rainf6);

$combined = array_combine($date_array, $rainf_array);

foreach ($combined as $key => $value) {
  $input .= $key . ' ' . $value . "\n";
}
```

Then save `$input` into the file.

Comment: Just a quick question I didn't understand the '$combined' function? Is there anywhere I could get more clarification? Thank you

Comment: @vorandasb The ```array_combine``` function creates an array (```$combined```) by using one array (```$date_array```) for keys and another (```$rainf_array```) for its values. See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php